# python issue to join relative url to absolute url for img

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm facing the following issues with my current code to make it work. I just concatenate the URL but its not working:

Current relative path (this is what I get with normal response.xpath crawl):

```
/imagename.jpg
```

This is my current code:

```
class MercadoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'extractor'
    item_count = 0

    rules = {
        # Para cada item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow = (), restrict_xpaths = ('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[7]/a'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =(), restrict_xpaths = ('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/h4/a')),
                            callback = 'parse_item', follow = False)
    }

    def parse_item(self, response):
        ml_item = MercadoItem()
        ml_item['titulo'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/h2)').extract_first()
        ml_item['sku'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a)').extract()
        ml_item['marca'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a)').extract()
        ml_item['tecnologia'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="DetailedSpecs"]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td)').extract_first()
        ml_item['tipo'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="DetailedSpecs"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td)').extract()
        ml_item['precio'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2])').extract()
        ml_item['color'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="mainC"]/div/div/div/div/ul/li/b)').extract()
        ml_item['potencia'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="ProductReview"]/div/div/div/dl/dd/strong)').extract()
        ml_item['condicion'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@class="stock in-stock"])').extract_first()
        ml_item['desc_corta'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="tab-additional_information"])').extract()
        ml_item['descripcion'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div)').extract()
        ml_item['id_publicacion'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@id="mainC"]/div/div/div[11]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/b)').extract()
        #imagenes del producto
        xpath1 = 'http://www.website.com.ar'
        xpath2 = response.xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p/img/@src').extract_first()
        ml_item['image_urls'] = xpath1 + xpath2
        ml_item['image_name'] = response.xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p/img/@src').extract()
        #info de la tienda o vendedor
        ml_item['categoria'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//*[@class="woocommerce-breadcrumb breadcrumbs"])').extract_first()
        self.item_count += 1
        if self.item_count > 10000:
            raise CloseSpider('item_exceeded')
        yield ml_item
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question what you are trying to achieve. What is the expected behaviour and what are you getting instead? Instead of posting parts of the code that are unrelevant for answering the question, please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Im needing to crawl images from a ecommerce website (product photo) but the html of the img code is only pointing with the relative path (on src of the img tag) so scrapy is giving me several errors because it requires the absolute image path to crawl them.

Comment: @GabrielAlejandro you should use `urljoin()` function to get full image path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> absolute_url = response.urljoin(your_url_from_xpath)

[scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin)

Comment: I've replaced response.xpath to response.urljoin but I get the following error on console:ml_item['image_urls'] = response.urljoin('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p/img/@src').extract()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extract'

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix it, I made the following correction:

  image = response.xpath('//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p/img/@src')
  ml_item['image_urls'] = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url, u) for u in image.extract()]